# How should I terminate all the tasks immediately

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

I use ThreadPoolExecutor to currently execute some tasks:

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(xxx))
tasks = [executor.submit(xxx) for x in xxx]
```

Then, I want to terminate all the tasks if timeout:

```
while not all_tasks_finished(tasks):
    if datetime.now() - start_time > timedelta(seconds=60):
        # executor.shutdown(False)??
```

It seems that executor.shutdown() would not executed until all the tasks finished. I wonder if there are any function to terminate tasks that were not finished

Answer (score 0):

try [canceling the Futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.cancel) returned by submit, first:

```py
while not all_tasks_finished(tasks):
    if datetime.now() - start_time > timedelta(seconds=60):
        for t in tasks:
            t.cancel()
        executor.shutdown()
```

Comment: But it seems that t.cancel() could only cancel tasks that were not put into threadpools. How could I cancel task that was already in running state?